# Android Get value from String array

Tags: java, android, arrays, dialog

I simply want a dialog box to appear showing the values in the array. Then on the button click, I want to get the value of the selected radio button and show it in a toast. Thanks for the answer in advance! It is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.moredialogs;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Next extends Activity {

private Context mContext; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);

    mContext = this;


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Show dialog");

        final CharSequence[] choiceList = 
        {"Coke", "Pepsi" , "Sprite" , "Seven Up" };

        int selected = 0; 


        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(choiceList, selected, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        // This is where I want the value to be selected


                    }


        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Sounds Good", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                // or return them to the component that opened the dialog

               // On button click I want the selected Item to go in here
            }

        });
        builder.show();
}

 }
```

Comment: Ok, which part are you stuck on? What's the question?

Comment: I am stuck on the onClick listener parts, what is the correct way to get the value of array choiceList and display it? I want to do it through java and not the xml. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first - create a field `mSelected`:

```
private int mSelected;
```

In your `ChoiceListener` set value to `mSelected`:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(choiceList, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        mSelected = arg1;
    }
});
```

In your `ButtonClickListener` just show a `Toast` and dismiss:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Sounds Good", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        final CharSequence item = choiceList[mSelected];
        Toast.makeText(mContext, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make `selected` into a field. Then

```
// This is where I want the value to be selected
```

should become:

```
selected = arg1;
```

Then in the listener:

```
Toast.makeText(
    Next.this,
    "Selected " + choiceList[selected],
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
.show();
```